# Custom JSP Tag which include another JSP

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, taglib, angularjs-ng-template

I want to create a custom JSP tag as follows.

```
<ng:template src="../js/Rule/templates/rule-list.jsp" />
```

Which will actually include the file "../js/Rule/templates/rule-list.jsp" inside a scripts tag and generate HTML as follows.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="../js/Rule/templates/rule-list.jsp">
    Content of ../js/Rule/templates/rule-list.jsp file
</script>
```

So far I have creates following tagfile.

```
<%@ attribute name="src" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="${src}">
    <%@ include file="${src}" %>
</script>
```

Which is giving this error

> File "${src}" not found

Means its trying to include the ${src} instated of its value. Can any one suggest how to include file in tag file from specified attribute value?

**Note**: I am using angularjs. I want to load angularjs templates without ajax call. Because my browser is not able to load ng-template with AJAX call for cross domain call problem.

Comment: I am following this tutorial http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm

Comment: Are you `JSP` files inside your `WEB-INF` folder by any chance?

Comment: My src attribute will hold JSP file path. Relative from the file where the tag is been used. But those JSP files will not be stored in WEB-INF. Only tag file here "template.tag" which contain tag definition can be stored on WEB-INF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I need to use dynamic include as

```
<jsp:include page="${src}" />
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`WEB-INF` directory is a special directory that is **not** part of the public directory tree of your web (Servlet) application.

The [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1449572011_60de24f8e105c1f2aa4e5d3a965ab44c) states (page 70 or so):

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   “WEB-INF”. This directory contains all things related to the
>   application that aren’t in the document root of the application. **The
>   WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the
>   application.** No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served
>   directly to a client by the container. However, the contents of the
>   WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the `getResource` and
>   `getResourceAsStream` method calls on the `ServletContext`, and may be
>   exposed using the RequestDispatcher calls.

AngularJS cannot see any folder inside your web application WEB-INF folder since it has no "connection" to it.

You will have to add those template files in a public folder, view-able by your Angular template files.

Comment: :) Need to use dynamic include. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Don't forget to answer the correct answer that worked/helped. :)

Comment: I have those template file in public folder. And my angular apps are running fine. I just wanted to change the way of template loading. Because my production server does not support template loading via AJAX call for cross domain related problem.